# Smart Contract Integration with Ether.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I've been trying to link a smart contract with ethers.js in my project.

```
const Provider= new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/`
const TokenContract = new ethers.Contract( TokenAddress, abiSource.token.abi, Provider );
);
```

I tried to run this but couldn't get the balance of the token contract. Extracted RPC link from the Metamask. Who can help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insert Infura Georli API key in your Provider.

```html
const Provider= new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/YOUR_API_KEY_HERE`
);
```

[https://docs.infura.io/networks/ethereum/how-to/secure-a-project/project-id](https://Document)